# jquery / javascript Load different content depending on session

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i have this code here:

```
    $('#internet').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/sessionset.php",
                success: function (data){
                    if (data == 1){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            //add variables
                            url: "ajax/loggedin.php",
                            success: function(data2){
                                //history.pushState({"internet.php?view=internetlog");
                                $('#internetlog').html(data2);


                    }
                        });
                    }    
                    else if(data===0){
                         alert("suka");

                        }

                } 

    });
});
```

The sessionset.php returns a value of either 1 or 0, depending if the session is currently going on or not.

Problem here is the link $('#internet')
returns the url loggedin.php when the data value is 1.
However if the data value is 0, nothing happens, since the e.preventDefault(); prevents any events.

Already checked on firebug that it either returns values of 1 or 0, I dont understand why the alert is not firing off when the value returned is 0...

edit: just checked the sessionset.php in a separate window instead of firebug

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!empty($_SESSION['origuserip'] && $_SESSION['loggedin'])){

    $switch = "1";
}   

else {
    $switch = "0";
}

echo $switch;
```

the return value of 1 is 1 however if !empty is false it returns

```
Notice: Undefined index: origuserip in ajax\sessionset.php on line 4
0
```

SOLUTION:

Guess the simplest way is just the best way -_-

```
    else {
("suka");

  }
```

Comment: What element is the click bind on? I'm not sure why you use preventDefault on click? Is this submit button?

Comment: normal a href, and just kept investigating further might be because of the sessionset.php  ill add it in the main post

Comment: Is the return value a string? If so, "0" !== 0

Comment: just updated it, maybe the undefined notice is messing up the value?

Comment: i think if you use ajax and php, better using json. This way you would not mess variable types

Answer (score 0):

The scripts return value is probably a string, because you didn't specify the return type of your AJAX call.

You should validate like this: `data==="1"` and `data==="0"`. Which checks for identity, as long as you definitely return strings.

`data==1` is always `true`, if it's set and not `null`.

Regarding the other problem:

Make sure your `$_SESSION` variables are set properly when you check their indexes and separate the `empty()` checks. For example like this:

```
    if (!empty($_SESSION['origuserip']) && !empty($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
        $switch = "1";
    }   
    else {
        $switch = "0";
    }

    echo $switch;
```